# Controller error when token isn't in the database

Tags: symfony, symfony5

I'm currently creating a password reset functionnality for my website in Symfony 5 and since yesterday an error is killing my brain.

In my controller I have this :

```
/**
 * @Route("/reset/{token}", name="reset")
 */
public function reset(User $user, Request $request, UserPasswordEncoderInterface $passwordEncoder, $token)
{ 
    //...
}
```

If I'm on my website with this URL `localhost:8000/reset/VALID_TOKEN`, everything is up and running.
But if the token is invalid (no occurences in the database), I got this error :

> App\Entity\User object not found by the @ParamConverter annotation.

I found that it was due to the `User $user` parameter in my function but I don't understand how and where Symfony is processing this User object. I'm just giving it a token and he automatically find the corresponding user (and that's what I want).

My goal is to prevent the case where the token is wrong and redirect the user to another page.

Comment: this is more of a security function and the $user should not be in the function head.

Answer (score 0):

To access the currently logged in user (disregarding the token for now), can and should be done by calling `$user = $this->getUser();` in the controller - and NOT by adding the User to the method head (so remove that).

you can then check:

```
if($user->getToken() != $token) {
    return $this->redirect....
}
```

you should remove the ParamConverter annotation if that's what you wanted.

original answer below:

---

`User` is an entity and as such can't be provided by the autowiring of symfony. The fallback for controller function parameters is to use the ParamConverter to somehow fetch the User from the repository using appropriate placeholders of your query. Using `{token}` (its value) as the identifier (by default `id`) - apparently doesn't work either. It isn't smart enough to gather that with `{token}` you want to query the User entities whose `token` property is the value.

This leads to your error message.

If you actually want to use the token to fetch a User with the ParamConverter, you have to provide it with some hints on how to do this.

You could add the following annotation (you may have to add a use clause `use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\ParamConverter;`):

```
@ParamConverter("user", options={"mapping": {"token": "token"}})
```

assuming the token is part of your User entity and stored in the database.

Source: https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/converters.html

Comment: I added the ParamConverter below my route and I'm still having the same error.
It seems like when the token isn't valid, he don't find the user so he gives me an error.

Comment: @EnzoKilm yeah, that is to be expected. What else would he do? Where is the user supposed to come from then?

Comment: Yes I know but what can I do to prevent this error ? The error is raised before the start of the function so I have no way to prevent this

Comment: If you want to do something when the User is not found, you can do it only if you don't relly on param converter. Because with the param converter, you will get a 404 before entering the controller action itself.

Comment: So the best in my case would be to fetch the user in database with the token and get if from there instead of using User as a parameter of my function ?

Comment: Exactly. This way you could verify that the User is null or not and then do your redirection